# C++ winsock error

Tags: c++, winsock

i have a simple server that accepts clients.
The client connect to the server. The first thing the server will do the following:

1. grab the client socket
2. create a thread for client
3. call ::recv();

the problem here is that recv returnes -1 
WSAGetLastError returnes WSAENOTSOCK: (Socket operation on nonsocket.) Microsoft: "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid." i can't really figure out what the problem really is.

the client has the socket still valid , and any recv the client dose will instantly return

Thanks, Raxvan

Comment: Any chance you could post some example code? It would make it easier for us to debug. I guess grub should have been 'grab' ?

Comment: it is the most basic server
SOCKER s = ::accept(lsock,0,0);
Cient* c= new Client(s);
c->RunThread();//here the thread will be created and started

Comment: Have you tried doing it without the threading for a moment ...and if so, can you post a working example?

Comment: Hmm.... no , i will try this now

Comment: On the same thread recv() works fine, it stops and waits for data. But on the client thread recv() will fail the first time is called. I checked the socket and is still the same one that accept() returned
accept returned for example (1839) and the client had the same value in the socket

Comment: Is it possible the calling thread goes out of scope or something like that before the socket is used in your child thread? It's hard to give much more advice without a solid code sample to debug..

Comment: i have added the main server code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that's easy.

In your code, you have

```
        inline sok  Accept()
```

that returns a `sok` by value.

Here you assign it to a local variable:

```
        sok client = listener.Accept();
```

and at the end of this expression, the temporary `sok` returned from Accept() gets destroyed. You might want to put a breakpoint or a debug print in `sok::Close()` to see what I mean with your own eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty much sure that you just immediately close the socket of the newly accepted connection.

You make use of the `sok` class, which closes the socket automatically at its d'tor (destructor).

```
sok client = listener.Accept();
```

The following code constructs the `sok` object from the returned socket. Its lifetime is bounded by the curly braces of the `while` loop.
Means - immediately after creating a thread that is supposed to read from the socket- you close it.

P.S.
You misuse the `sok`. According to what it's doing you **must** prevent creation of more than one such an object for the same socket.

For instance the copy c'tor must be declared private. And it's public at your code.
Also it's a good idea to declare the c'tor that takes a SOCKET with `explicit` keyword.

Conclusion: think and review your usage of `sok` class.

Answer (score 0):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#winsock.wsaenotsock_2), there was a problem with the socket.

> An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid.

How did you 'grub' the socket - are you sure it's valid? Try checking the return from `::accept`. If the return value == INVALID_SOCKET, then that's your problem. You can call [WSAGetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741580%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to try and identify the problem then.

Comment: yea it is i call WSAGetLastError just after accept and there are no error. The returned socket from accept() is valid

Comment: yes it is a valid value, different from INVALID_SOCKET.
accept() dose not fail in any way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void NetworkServer::RunServer()//main server loop
    {
        while (flags & server_running)
        {
            sok client = listener.Accept();
            if (listener && client.IsValid())
            {
                if (clients.size >= MaxClients)
                {
                    client.Close();
                    continue;
                }
                ClientHandler* h = constructor->ConstructClient();
//ConstructClient() is just doing "new ClientHandler()";
                h->com_stream.forceConnected(client);
                h->id = client_ids.getId();
                h->flags = client_active;
                h->server = this;
                this->HandleNewConnection(h);//nothing..

                locker.Enter();
                clients.add(h);//add client to the client array
                h->threadRun();//stars the thread

                locker.Leave();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    void tcpStream::forceConnected(sok& ss)
    {
        server.socket = ss.socket;
        connected = true;
    }



class sok
    {
    private:
        SOCKET      socket;
    public:
        inline      sok()
            : socket(INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
        }
        inline      sok(SOCKET s)
            : socket(s)
        {
        }
        inline      sok(const sok & s)
            : socket(s.socket)
        {
        }
        inline      operator bool()const
        {
            return (socket != INVALID_SOCKET);
        }
        inline      ~sok()
        {
            Close();
        }
        inline bool IsValid()const
        {
            return (socket != INVALID_SOCKET);
        }
        inline void operator = (const sok & s)
        {
            socket = s.socket;
        }
    public:
        inline void Close()
        {
            if (socket != INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                closesocket(socket);
                socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            }
        }
        inline sok  Accept()
        {
            return sok(::accept(socket, 0, 0));
        }
        bool        tcpClient(NetAddress& adr);
        bool        tcpServer(wtf::ushort port, wtf::u32 clients = 10);
    private:
        friend class tcpStream;
    };

uint tcpStream::read(void* out, const uint size)
{
    wtf::n32 r = ::recv(server.socket, (char*)out, size, 0);//this failes
    //int e = WSAGetLastError();
    connected = ((r) != (-1));
    return ((uint)r);/**/
}
```

Comment: the member com_stream in the client is of type tcpStream.
tcpSteam is just wrappe around the socket for reading and writing

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you pass the recv() function the correct parameters, INCLUDING the correct socket's id (it's an "unsigned int" anyway!).